# Would angularjs work locally?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Would pure angular and css/html work in a local machine?

In my case, I'm not getting any errors, but at the same time the messages won't show any output. Any idea why?

Some of the code:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/C:somethinghere\style.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/C:somethinghere\app.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="parent" ng-app="myApp">
{{ messages }}
</div>
```

app:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.messages = "hello";
    $scope.ratings = [{test: 22},{test: 99}];
}]);
```

NOTE: the links are correct, i just changed the links to now show my username.

Comment: If you literally have `/C:` at the beginning of your local paths, then the problem is there: the paths are most likely wrong. Look at the browser's network tab to see the errors. If you can you should use relative paths.

Comment: path is not wrong. i just changed them in the post here.

Comment: I'm not saying that the path is wrong, I'm saying that the way you add them to the href/src attributes is wrong. Does the network tab say that they get loaded correctly?

Comment: i think so. no errors in console log, and when im checking the source-view, and clicks the links, the links works.

Comment: You're missing a `<div ng-controller="GreetingController">` above `{{ messages }}` and a `</body>` closing tag in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer is: Yes, angular works on a local machine.**

The problem in your code is that you are not assigning the controller to the view, you are missing the `ng-controller="GreetingController"` inside your view.

So to fix that, just enclose `{{ messages }}` inside a `div` tag with `ng-controller` attribute.

A solution might look like that:

```
<body class="parent" ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="GreetingController">
      {{ messages }}
   </div>
</body>
```

**Also, please notice that in your HTML, you opened a `<body>` tag but you closed it with `</div>` tag. You missed the `</body>` enclosing tag and you missed a `<div>` opening tag.**

**Another small tip:**

Try to use relative paths instead of absolute paths when you load CSS/JS files.

Just write `<link href='styles/style.css'>` instead of `<link href='c:/.../styles/style.css'>`. This path assumes that you have a `styles` folder in the same folder that your HTML file exists.